# Are "вес(а)" и "гиря" synonyms?

Tags: цитата

Here's a quote from Checkov: "в том нужны грехи на веса и добрые дела вместо гирь". I don't think that in this context "вес" and "гиря" are synonyms, or are they?

Comment: Can you copy more text, some of previous and following sentences?

Comment: Here is a context: Дражайший Брат Миша!

Я сейчас сделал 2 выстрела: один в забор из ружья, другой в Сашу из-под пера. Я выстрелил в него тостом: "Пусть твоя математическая слава и ученость раздадутся, как этот выстрел в сем мире" (но не в том; в том нужны грехи на веса и добрые дела вместо гирь). Какой бы тебе сделать выстрел такой, чтоб ружье осечки не дало? Кладу 2 заряда, и пли! Выстрел удачен! Ружья не разорвало, но перо чуть не поломалось.

Answer (score 3):

No they are not. Веса here is used as "весы", scales.
I am not sure about the historical usage of this particular form.

Answer (score 3):

> "Пусть твоя математическая слава и ученость раздадутся, как этот выстрел в сем мире" (но не в том; в том нужны грехи на веса и добрые дела вместо гирь).

First of all **веса** is an old form from весы-scales, **гиря** is weight which you put on one pan of the scales.
The meaning of the sentence is the following. "May your fame in the world of Maths be heard like this shot in this world,living,not that one,of the dead,(in that world you need your sins put on one scale(pan) and your good deeds on the other scale as weight.)" You will go either to paradise or to hell depending on what is heavier,your sins or your good deeds.

The words are not synonyms.

Comment: That's not quite right. the word "веса" is kind of synonym of "гири". But "гири" is used for both things you put on scales to weight something and for the thing you use in gym, while "веса" is only used for the first of those meanings. And it is not a form of word "весы" (scales), it is plural of "вес" (weight).

Comment: Кружат над землёй черных воронов тучи.
Божественным светом текут небеса.
Однажды Всевышний мир сделает лучше –
И грех, и любовь, положив на веса.